# Rails define nil check on record in model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a Rails application which stores information on children, certain fields would make a `child` anaphylactic and I want to be able to define a method in my `Child` model so that I can perform a check on a record for anaphylaxis. For example a `child` is anaphylactic if 10 certain fields are `nil`. I do not want to write out `@anaphylactic_kids = Kid.where( . . . and . . . and . . .)` as it would be really long. Is there a simpler way to do this? Thanks for all help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't an easy way to avoid writing the full `where` clause out at least once, but you can avoid having to write it into *every* controller action you want to use it in by creating a scope for it.

In your model, add this method:

```
def self.anaphylactic
  Kid.where(:field1 => nil, :field2 => nil, :field3 => nil)
  # complete the where clause for every field you need to check
end
```

Now instead of using the full `Kid.where` statement in your controllers, you can simply call `Kid.anaphylactic` to get the same results.

Comment: You can also define named scope, but solution proposed by ArtOfCode is better IMO. Also bare in mind this SQL explain for such query maybe big and in future proper indices would be sufficient

Comment: @Sebastian named scopes and model class methods are almost the same thing - there's a few differences, but they perform the same function in the end

Comment: this seems to be the exact idea i was looking for, thank you!